# Picasso doesn't load drawable image into ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, picasso

`Picasso` can't load image `drawable` into `ImageView`, I've tried to change `ImageView`'s width and height, resizing image, loading it with and without `fit()`, `resize()` or `center()` and image is stil not visible. I am using `Picasso` at whole project, and everywhere works fine, but it gives no result at this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainFullFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/mainThemeBlack"
    tools:context=".MainTabsActivity">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlSynchroView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/bottom_sheet_blue">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSynchroLast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
            android:text="Last synchro: 10:38"/>



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSynchroIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvSynchroLast"
            android:elevation="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listFullView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:layout_above="@id/rlSynchroView"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:divider="@color/mainThemeBlack"
        android:paddingBottom="70dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Method call:

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.refresh_icon)
                .resize(10, 10)
                .into(refreshIV);
```

I am calling it inside `onViewCreated()` and I've tried to resize it with different values too.

I want to achieve clickable bottom bar with refresh icon (and info about time of last synchro), to synchronize data with service inside `onClick` method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_full, container, false);

        refreshIV = mView.findViewById(R.id.ivSynchroIcon);

        mobileArray = new ArrayList<IssuePOJO>(); 
        dbStats.open();

        generateList();

        mView = view;
        return mView;

    }
```

Comment: where is `refreshIV` ?

Comment: I've edited my question, mView is global for this Fragment, so i can use it everywhere for findViewById()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picasso syntax looks correct, but looks like onCreateView method logic is incorrect

Please try with below code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_full, container, false);

    refreshIV = mView.findViewById(R.id.ivSynchroIcon);

    mobileArray = new ArrayList<IssuePOJO>(); 
    dbStats.open();

    generateList();

    //mView = view;//please comment this one and try
    return mView;

}
```

Comment: @SkypeDogg please check my answer

Comment: You are welcome and thank you for accepting the answer, happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

you are loading it into wrong Imageview . Change your code like this

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.refresh_icon).into(ivSynchroIcon);
```

If you want to see what goes wrong , just add PIcasso callback like this

```
 Picasso.get()
            .load(R.drawable.refresh_icon)
            .into(ivSynchroIcon, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                }
            })
```

Comment: I've edited, `refreshIV = mView.findViewById(R.id.ivSynchroIcon);`

Comment: @SkypeDogg . see updated answer . now print your exception and success both . see what happens

Comment: I've set it to print "success" on success, and `e.getMessage()` on error, and here's what I've got: `02-21 13:12:27.677 32724-32724/com.example.damianadamski.Service D/PICASSO: success` .Looks like it works fine, but still no image loaded

Comment: Background for layout is blue, icon is white with transparent background. No idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: @SkypeDogg try with different image for testing

Comment: I've tried 3 other drawables which I use in project, but without result

Comment: i don't think there will be any issues now. its all perfect. but just make you are using jpg or png image . try with different image , clean and build your project. and make sure your imageview is visible in design also

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the drawable (refresh_icon) in your resources, you may put it directly in the layout.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSynchroIcon"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSynchroLast"
    android:src="@drawable/refresh_icon"
    android:elevation="5dp"/>
```

If you want to use Picasso anyway, try checking the ivSynchroIcon element in Layout Inspector.
So, you can see where the imageview is placed, and the measurements as well.
In Android Studio `Tools -> Layout Inspector`

Comment: `refresh_icon` is 128x128 so I'm not sure if it gonna be resized from XML

Comment: Your rlSynchroView layout's height is 70dp. So just give width=70dp, height=70dp. And if you want, you can make the icon smaller by adding padding. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this line

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(10, 10).into(refreshIV);
```

Answer (score -2):

Picasso is having this problem you should try using placeholder with you drawable

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.refresh_icon)
            .resize(10, 10)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.refresh_icon)
            .into(refreshIV);
```

Comment: why are you using a placeholder?